# commandButton actionListener isn"t called when an other component is required

Tags: primefaces, actionlistener, commandbutton

I tried `<p:commandButton>` as shown above, it works correctly.

```
<p:spinner id="spinnerQte" min="1" value="#{newOpProgramme.quantite}"/>     
<p:commandButton id="AjoutEquip" value="Ajouter" actionListener="#{newOpProgramme.addEquipement()}" update="spinnerQte"/>
```

But, when I tried ti nest this in my global page inside layout, panel, panel-Grid and field-Set, `addEquipement()` method is not called !

also, thee some fields which have required attribute set to true, I think this is why `addEquipement()` method isn't called.

Have you an Idea how to fix the problem.

thank you

Comment: Any javascript errors? Server logs which show some errors? Maybe an exception in any of your setters? If there a `h:form` wrapped around? You can omit the parenthesis when using `actionListener` and not passing any parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding process attribute to `<p:commandButton>` set to `@this`.